# Cannot set custom fontsize on minted package after setting custom sans font using fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, fontsize, minted

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[CalibriLight]{
  Extension      = .TTF                     ,
  UprightFont    = fonts/Calibri-Light      ,
  ItalicFont     = fonts/Calibri-Light-Italic   ,
  BoldFont       = fonts/Calibri-Light-Bold     ,
  BoldItalicFont = fonts/Calibri-Light-Bold-Italic
}

\defaultfontfeatures[Calibri]{
  Extension      = .TTF                             ,
  UprightFont    = fonts/Calibri-Light-Bold             ,
  ItalicFont     = fonts/Calibri-Light-Bold-Italic  ,
  BoldFont       = fonts/Calibri-Bold                   ,
  BoldItalicFont = fonts/Calibri-Bold-Italic
}

\newfontfamily{\calibri}[Scale=1.2]{Calibri}
\setsansfont[Scale=1.2]{CalibriLight}

\setminted[matlab]{linenos=true, frame=single, framesep=5pt, fontsize=10pt}

\begin{document}
\inputminted{matlab}{file.m}
\end{document}
```

I've left in only the part of the source that's relevant to my problem, I've created a custom font because I need to use Calibri for my report section/subsection headings.

The source above gives errors, but it works fine if I set fontsize to something like \small instead of a value like 10pt.

These are the contents of file.m:
`clear 'all'
    clc
    load foobar;
    soundsc(foobar1, 8000);
    %soundsc(foobar1, 4000);
    %soundsc(foobar1, 2000);`

And this is the error I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.8 \end{Verbatim}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.8 \end{Verbatim}
Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
)
Overfull \hbox (38.29774pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--28
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10.95 10pt[][][]
[]
[1
] (test.aux) )
```

The line numbers will match with the source I've provided above, and as I mentioned earlier, simply changing the fontsize to \small instead of 10pt fixes the issue, but it doesn't achieve what I require.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)  to TeX.SX!

Comment: what error do you get (and does it depend on `file.m` (which we don't have)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have updated my post with the information you require, please let me know of anything else you require and I will update my post as necessary. Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing `\defaultfontfeatures`:

```
\newfontfamily{\calibrilight}{Calibri-Light}[
  Extension      = .TTF,
  Path           = ./fonts/,
  Scale          = 1.2,
  UprightFont    = *,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Bold-Italic,
]

\setsansfont{Calibri}[
  Extension      = .TTF,
  Path           = ./fonts/,
  Scale          = 1.2,
  UprightFont    = *-Light-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Light-Bold-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-Bold-Italic,
]
```

Complete example (but using ClearSans as I don't own Calibri); adjust the font names to suit you.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
clear 'all'
clc
load foobar;
soundsc(foobar1, 8000);
%soundsc(foobar1, 4000);
%soundsc(foobar1, 2000);
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontfamily{\calibrilight}{ClearSans}[
%  Extension      = .TTF,
%  Path           = ./fonts/,
  Scale          = 1.2,
  UprightFont    = *,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]

\setsansfont{ClearSans}[
%  Extension      = .TTF,
%  Path           = ./fonts/,
  Scale          = 1.2,
  UprightFont    = *-Medium,
  ItalicFont     = *-MediumItalic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]

\setminted[matlab]{linenos=true, frame=single, framesep=5pt, fontsize=\small}

\begin{document}

\section{This is in ClearSans}

\lipsum[1]

Normal sans: {\sffamily Whatever \textbf{bold}}

Light sans: {\calibrilight Whatever \textbf{bold}}

\inputminted{matlab}{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please explain to me how I misused it? I tried replacing the default font features portion with the block you answered with which gave me more errors... On another note, what I wanted to accomplish is setting Calibri-Light as my default sans font family and having a custom font family for Calibri which I used for my section headings.

Comment: @Romtromon I'm not sure I follow you; the options you gave for `\defaultfontfeatures` are proper of `\setXfont` or `\newfontfamily`. Since I don't own Calibri Light, I can't test.

Comment: @Romtromon There was a typo that caused errors: the final `}` should have been `]`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but my issue sadly isn't solved yet. The script compiles fine when the fontsize is set to \small for minted but not when I set it to a value like 10pt, which is what I want to do. I am also unsure of why you included the package lipsum, I did not do that.

Comment: @Romtromon You can't do `fontsize=10pt`; the only admissible values are font size changing *commands* such as `\small`. If the overall font size is 11pt (like in your case), `\small` chooses 10pt size. The `lipsum` package is just for providing filler text.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. What can I do in a situation where \small is too large and \tiny is too small? Because that's the problem I'm having right now (I was just trying 10pt as a test I wanted it smaller.)

Comment: @Romtromon  In increasing order: `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small` and `\normalsize`. Or you can do `\fontsize{8.5}{11}\selectfont` (the second parameter is the interline skip).